# PostgreSQL surrogate keys: use sequence/bigint or OID?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, sequence, surrogate-key, citus

I'm looking at a need for surrogate keys in tables I'm designing on a PostgreSQL-derived DBMS ([Citus](https://www.citusdata.com/)). Would OIDs suffice? Is there a downside to using them instead of creating a `bigint` field and a sequence?

Comment: OIDs are deprecated, don't use them. Use a `bigserial`

Comment: thanks horsie.  I consider this an answer.  So I should always have (OIDS=false)?  Can you point out where the docs say it's deprecated?

Comment: @Andre "The oid type is currently implemented as an unsigned four-byte integer. Therefore, it is not large enough to provide database-wide uniqueness in large databases, or even in large individual tables. So, using a user-created table's OID column as a primary key is discouraged. OIDs are best used only for references to system tables." http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-oid.html. I couldn't find reference to deprecated but atleast discouraged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OIDS**

From Docs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-oid.html

> The oid type is currently implemented as an unsigned four-byte
>   integer. Therefore, it is not large enough to provide database-wide
>   uniqueness in large databases, or even in large individual tables. So,
>   using a user-created table's OID column as a primary key is
>   discouraged. OIDs are best used only for references to system tables.

**bigint and a sequence**

As "_a_horse_with no_name" suggested use bigserial

- smallserial  2 bytes
- serial   4 bytes
- bigserial    8 bytes

Notice: smallserial and serial don't seem to overcome the size limitation of 4 bytes specified above. Probably someone else can fill in on that.

> The data types smallserial, serial and bigserial are not true types,
>   but merely a notational convenience for creating unique identifier
>   columns (similar to the AUTO_INCREMENT property supported by some
>   other databases)

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of misunderstandings floating around here.

OIDs were included with every row by default in very old versions of Postgres. The default was soon changed to *not* include OID columns in user-defined tables.

Quoting the [Postgres 8.1 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-DEFAULT-WITH-OIDS):

> `default_with_oids` (`boolean`)
>
> This controls whether `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE TABLE AS` include an OID
>   column in newly-created tables, if neither `WITH OIDS` nor `WITHOUT OIDS`
>   is specified. It also determines whether OIDs will be included in
>   tables created by `SELECT INTO`. In **PostgreSQL 8.1** `default_with_oids` is
>   disabled by default; in prior versions of PostgreSQL, it was on by default.

Bold emphasis mine. What [@Shire quoted](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/127947/3684) is related, but **OIDs are not even considered for a PK in modern Postgres**.

The obvious reason why [@a_horse (correctly) suggested](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/127943/postgresql-surrogate-keys-use-sequences-bigint-or-oid/127954#comment237257_127943) [**`bigserial`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) (and not just `serial`) is in the question:

> Is there a downside to using them instead of creating a **`bigint`** field and a sequence?

Bold emphasis mine again. Typically, a `serial` column (implemented with a 4-byte integer) is good enough for most tables - unless you expect more than 2 billion ([`2^31 - 1 = 2.147.483.647`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-NUMERIC-TABLE)) rows over the lifetime of the table.